# Is it possible to get the declaration object name using runtime(objective-c)?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

guys
I am just interested in to get the declaration object name;
what I mean:

```
NSString *myObjectString = @"some string";
//some code 
//and in the end I want to get something like that:
NSString *myOName = @"myobjectstring";
```

Thanks in advance;

Comment: probably you want to have a up to date key to be used with KVO. There is no such feature in Objective C (at least I don't know it). Defining own constant is only option.

Comment: Unfortunatly no, just want to know the name; Thank you btw;

Answer (score 0):

You can use macros

```
#define NAME_STRING(string) @#string
```

and use it the following way:

```
NSString *myOName = NAME_STRING(myObjectString);
```

Answer (score 0):

This macro could be used as definition of global or local variable, it won't work for properties or fields.

```
#define VAR_WITH_NAME(varType, varName) \
    varType varName; \
    static NSString * const varName ## _name = @#varName ;

……
VAR_WITH_NAME(NSString *, myVar);
myVar = @"tada";
NSLog(@"%@=%@", myVar_name, myVar);
```

IMO you requirement is strange.